# Detect Bump on No internet stackoverflow

Tags: ios, connectivity, bump

When there is no Internet connection, is there a way to tell the user that they cannot Bump their iPhone to transfer data. I have used motionEnded: method to detect the shake, but the sensitivity is less compared to the Bump feature.

Any help?

Comment: You should never gate anything network related based on whether the iPhone believes there is a network available, because the act of attempting to use the network will often make it available.

Answer (score 0):

use apple's reachability class to check for connection availability and pop up a alertview with your desired message for user.

Comment: I have implemented that, but this should happen only when the user bump with another device. If I use motionEnded coupled with apple's reachability, I have to Bump with more energy, then what I get with Bump. Bump's sensitivity is more smoother.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. Can you tell more about what you are trying to achieve, what you have done so far?

Anyway If I am getting this right, you want to transfer data when there is no internet connection. Remember bluetooth? Apple has built a [GameKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) framework on top of it. You can explore that.

Comment: I don't want to transfer data when there is no internet connection. I just want to notify the user that He cannot transfer the data since there is no internet connection, when the user Bump the device.

Comment: thats easy. checking for internet connection. Try using this awesome project - https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability

Comment: I have already used Reachability to notify about no internet when trying to access the network. The issue is that when the user Bump the iPhone to transfer/exchange data, no block is executed or no event is called, when no internet.